# Fastest way to process OSM

Tags: python, postgresql, openstreetmap, c++

I've been working with `imposm` and Python, it's fairly easy to parallelise. I've hit a performance problem when trying to associate the coordinates to the ways.

Creating a dictionary from `coordinate_id` to `lat`,`long` and then using it turns out to be really slow.

Do you know of any alternatives that I can use?

Has anyone used a C++ library, or even Scala, or PostgreSQL

---

Btw, I've been able to iterate through 39GB of PBF, almost the whole globe in 17 minutes on a 32 core machine. That's the performance I'm looking for.

Comment: Which actual problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there are better solutions than your current approach.

Comment: to get the center of all the ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Osmium is a very fast and flexible C++ library for working with OSM data: http://osmcode.org/libosmium/

It supports all types of osm entities such as nodes, ways, relations and even historical osm data.
It's published under Boost Software License and therefore free to use.